# "paracol" doesn't work inside a beamer frame

Tags: beamer, equations, paracol

I was trying to make a slide for a class. But I had a problem with inserting equations at the right side of the text.

code for my slide:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\documentclass[mathserif]{beamer}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kotex}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{paracol}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!75!black}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=block title.bg!10!bg}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Chapter 2: Introduction}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Notion of a State
    \begin{itemize}
      \item All the information required at $t = t_{0}$ which, together with $u(t),\, t\geq t_{0}$, determines uniquely the output $y(t)$ for $t\geq t_{0}$. \break
    \end{itemize}
  \item Definition of a state (Definition 2.1 Chen p6)
    \begin{definition}
      The state $x(t_{0})$ of a system at time $t_{0}$ is the information at $t_{0}$ that, together with the input $u(t)$, for $t\geq t_{0}$, determines uniquely the output $y(t)$ for all $t\geq t_{0}$.
    \end{definition}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item State vector $x\in R^n$, input vector $u \in R^m$, output vector $y \in R^p$
    \end{itemize}
\begin{paracol}{2}
  \item State equation: $\dot{x} = f(x, u, t)$
  \item Output equation: $y = g(x, u, t)$ 
\switchcolumn
   $$\begin{rcases*}
      x(t_{0}) \\
     u(t), \, t\geq t_{0}
  \end{rcases*} \xrightarrow{} y(t), \, t\geq t_{0}$$
\end{paracol}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Then the equation is placed below the text, not the right side. When I copied the `paracol` part and pasted it in a new tex file, it worked well. I don't know why it has a problem.

And an error: not in outer par mode occurs as well. Does this affect to `paracol`?

Comment: Why don't you use beamer built in columns environment?

Comment: Changing the effective column width in the middle of an itemize is not a good idea, nor is needed.  enumerate can be fixed using enumitem and [resume]..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help of `beamer`'s built-in `column` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!75!black}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=block title.bg!10!bg}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Chapter 2: Introduction}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Notion of a State
    \begin{itemize}
      \item All the information required at $t = t_{0}$ which, together with $u(t),\, t\geq t_{0}$, determines uniquely the output $y(t)$ for $t\geq t_{0}$. 
    \end{itemize}
  \item Definition of a state (Definition 2.1 Chen p6)
    \begin{definition}
      The state $x(t_{0})$ of a system at time $t_{0}$ is the information at $t_{0}$ that, together with the input $u(t)$, for $t\geq t_{0}$, determines uniquely the output $y(t)$ for all $t\geq t_{0}$.
    \end{definition}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item State vector $x\in R^n$, input vector $u \in R^m$, output vector $y \in R^p$
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\begin{columns}
  \begin{column}{0.55\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item State equation: $\dot{x} = f(x, u, t)$
      \item Output equation: $y = g(x, u, t)$ 
    \end{itemize}
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}
     \[\begin{rcases*}
        x(t_{0}) \\
       u(t), \, t\geq t_{0}
    \end{rcases*} \xrightarrow{} y(t), \, t\geq t_{0}\]
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be the `paracol` inside the `frame` environment, which you can easily test by reducing your example to the minimal

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Intro}
        \begin{paracol}{2}
            A
            \switchcolumn
            B
        \end{paracol}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I do not know how to work around this with `paracol` but since you have a 50:50 column ratio anyways, would using `multicol` work for you?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage{kotex}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!75!black}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=block title.bg!10!bg}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}{Chapter 2: Introduction}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Notion of a State
            \begin{itemize}
                \item All the information required at $t = t_{0}$ which, together with $u(t),\, t\geq t_{0}$, determines uniquely the output $y(t)$ for $t\geq t_{0}$. \break
            \end{itemize}
            \item Definition of a state (Definition 2.1 Chen p6)
            \begin{definition}
                The state $x(t_{0})$ of a system at time $t_{0}$ is the information at $t_{0}$ that, together with the input $u(t)$, for $t\geq t_{0}$, determines uniquely the output $y(t)$ for all $t\geq t_{0}$.
            \end{definition}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item State vector $x\in R^n$, input vector $u \in R^m$, output vector $y \in R^p$
            \end{itemize}
            \begin{multicols}{2}
                \item State equation: $\dot{x} = f(x, u, t)$
                \item Output equation: $y = g(x, u, t)$ 
                
                $$\begin{rcases*}
                    x(t_{0}) \\
                    u(t), \, t\geq t_{0}
                \end{rcases*} \xrightarrow{} y(t), \, t\geq t_{0}$$
            \end{multicols}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Other options include `parcolumns` and `tabular`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But when using multicols(50:50 ratio), the text in the left column becomes 3 lines. Is there a way to reduce the left margin or adjusting the ratio in multicols?

Comment: I tried using the ``parcolums`` environment @Davislor suggested, but I am not familiar with the syntax of that package and couldn't align the two colums properly and ``tabular`` will not work in combination with ``itemize``...
Maybe someone who knows the ``parcolumns`` syntax can help.
Other than that, a last resort solution would be to place two ``minipage``s next to each other